# Gaussian-Likelihood with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, statistics

This is a TensorFlow code to calculate Maximum log-likelihood from this [link](https://github.com/openai/spinningup/blob/master/spinup/exercises/tf1/problem_set_1/exercise1_1.py).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

EPS=1e-8

def gaussian_likelihood(x, mu, log_std):
    pre_sum = -0.5 * (((x-mu)/(tf.exp(log_std)+EPS))**2 + 2*log_std + np.log(2*np.pi))
    return tf.reduce_sum(pre_sum, axis=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

     sess = tf.Session()

     dim = 2
     x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, dim))
     mu = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, dim))
     log_std = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(dim,))

     true_gaussian_likelihood = gaussian_likelihood(x, mu, log_std)

     batch_size = 5
     feed_dict = {x: np.random.rand(batch_size, dim),
             mu: np.random.rand(batch_size, dim),
             log_std: np.random.rand(dim)}

     true_result = sess.run(true_gaussian_likelihood,
                                    feed_dict=feed_dict)

     print(true_result)
```

In the last line of `gaussian_likelihood` function, why it has summed just over axis=1? I think the result of max-likelihood is a probability that is calculated over all samples(here batch_size=5 for simplicity) and should be just one number. But what I got as the max-likelihood is an array with (5,) dimension like below:

```
[-3.0391085 -3.0107908 -2.966611  -2.9552155 -3.027913 ]
```

Plus, these numbers aren't in the range [0,1] as the probability values should be. Is this a mistake of OpenAI tean who provided this code?

Comment: A log-likelihood is not a probability

Comment: @Matias, you are right. But why the result is a vector? shouldn't it be just a number that comes from a summation over all samples in on batch?